# Need documentation for implementing a MAC OSX application

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-leopard

I am very new to MAC OSX development but I had a good expirience with Xcode and Objectice-C. I tried to implement an application before that I just want to know different types of User-Interface elements like Menus, Windows, Controls and Layouts. I searched for these  Aqua Interface elements. Can any one please suggest me a good documentation to get the knowledge on this? and is there are any sample codes on this?

Thanks in Advance,
-S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Book: [http://www.amazon.com/Learn-Cocoa-Mac-Jack-Nutting/dp/1430218592/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1291790226&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218592)

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html

Samples: Ship with XCode, in `/Developer/Examples`. Try Sketch and TextEdit.